# Html page scrolling

Tags: html, css

My page doesn't scroll at all, if I change the window size, the content is just invisible if the page is too small. I've tried adding `overflow: auto;` and `overflow: scroll:` to many different tags, but this didn't work either.

Here's a snippet of the code, but see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a75jq5yu/) for the full code

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 }

header, ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 div.contentwrapper {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100%;
 }

div.left, div.right, div.mid {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
 }

footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href=""><img></a>
    <ul>my nav bar</ul>
  </header>
  <div class="contentwrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="upperleft"></div>
      <div class="lowerleft"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position fixed?

Comment: Try set `overflow: auto;` for html tag or body tag

Comment: `overflow: auto;` did not work for body or html

Comment: If my answer solved it, please mark as correct (green check). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: fixed;` from `div.wrapper` (and anything else you want to get scrolling).
Perhaps you meant `position: absolute;`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a75jq5yu/1/).

```css
div.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 }

header, ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 div.contentwrapper {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100%;
 }

div.left, div.right, div.mid {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
 }

footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href=""><img></a>
    <ul>my nav bar</ul>
  </header>
  <div class="contentwrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="upperleft"></div>
      <div class="lowerleft"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: changing the position to absolute in wrapper worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrapper set to position : fixed , you gotta change it. That will fix your problem.

```
  div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
   }
```

Comment: What is this adding to the previous answer? Or did you start typing before it was posted?

Comment: i started typing when there was no answer.

Comment: Well, that was really close! :)